# Multiple file project in golang

Tags: go

I have a project with 2 files :

[image]

Here is my main.go file :

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "math"

func main() {
    xs := []float64{1, 2, 3, 4}
    avg := math.Average(xs)
    fmt.Println(avg)
}
```

and my math.go  :

```
package math

func Average(xs []float64) float64 {
    total := float64(0)
    for _, x := range xs {
        total += x
    }
    return total / float64(len(xs))
}
```

But when i do :

```
> bussiere@kusanagi [06:44:01 PM] [~/Workspace/bdrun/TestPack/src]
> -> % go install .
> # _/home/bussiere/Workspace/bdrun/TestPack/src ./main.go:8:9: undefined: math.Average bussiere@kusanagi [06:47:12 PM]
> [~/Workspace/bdrun/TestPack/src]-> % go run main.go
> # command-line-arguments ./main.go:8:9: undefined: math.Average
```

How comes ?

Regards and thanks

Comment: Have you build your project before with `go build` ?

Comment: Your main package source is not in a package source directory, and neither is your `math` package. Please read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) in full.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close. What you have:

```
bin/
pkg/
  math.go
src/
  main.go
```

But this isn't what the `go` binary expects. Under the `src` folder should be a folder for each project:

```
src/
  myproject/
    math/
      math.go
    main.go
```

When you want a go file to be in a different package it should be in a folder of the same name as the new package. You'll need to update your math import. `import "math"` will import the standard library math file. Try `import "myproject/math"` in your main.go after making the tree structure above.

You don't have to worry about the pkg or bin folder. You won't normally need to go out of your way to put anything in them.